# Get expected Action Parameter type in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, query-string, custom-attributes, onactionexecuting

**Question:**
Is it possible to know the type of parameter that is expected by the action being called? For example, I have some `action` as:

```
[TestCustomAttr]
public ActionResult TestAction(int a, string b)
{
    ...
```

and `TestCustomAttr` is defined as:

```
public class TestCustomAttr : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
```

So when the call is made to `TestAction`, here, inside `OnActionExecuting`, i want to know the type expected by the `TestAction` method. (e.g: in this case, there are 2 expected parameters. one is of type `int` and other one is of type `string`.

**Actual Purpose:**
Actually i need to make changes to the values of `QueryString`. I'm already able to get the querystring values  (through `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`), change it, and then manually add it to `ActionParameters` as `filterContext.ActionParameters[key] = updatedValue;`

**Problem:**
Currently, i try to parse the value to `int`, if it is successfully parsed, i assume, it is an `int`, so I make the require change (eg value + 1), and then add it to action parameters, against its key.

```
 qsValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[someKey].ToString();

 if(Int32.TryParse(qsValue, out intValue))
 {
     //here i assume, expected parameter is of type `int`
 }
 else
 {
     //here i assume, expected parameter is of type 'string'
 }
```

but i want to know the exact expected type. because `string` can be as `"123"`, and it will be assumed to be `int` and added as integer parameter, causing null exception, for other parameter. (vice versa). Therefore i want to parse the updated value to exact expected type, and then add to action parameters, against its key. So, how can i do this? Is this even possible? May be `Reflection` can help someway?

**important:** I'm open to suggestions. If my approach is not good to achieve the actual purpose, or if there is a better way of doing it, please share ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the parameter from the ActionDescriptor.

```
public class TestCustomAttr : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ActionInfo = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var pars = ActionInfo.GetParameters();
        foreach (var p in pars)
        {

           var type = p.ParameterType; //get type expected
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for :) after this, i could easily get all expected parameters types and use them. 
`ReflectedActionDescriptor ActionInfo = (ReflectedActionDescriptor) filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
                    List<ParameterDescriptor> ExpectedParameters = ActionInfo.GetParameters().ToList();`